# i can't load sklearn on my raspberry pi

Tags: python, module, raspberry-pi, scikit-learn

I am trying to import sklearn in my python script but when i run the scrip it simply says:`Wating for all Temp files to load...`
This has gone on for several minutes and doesn't seem to be loading anything, it never happened to me before sklearn loads fine on my macbook and all other modules run smoothly on my Raspberry.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Keep in mind that I/O on a Raspberry Pi is substantially slower than on a Macbook (SD card vs. SSD).

Comment: But this has literally been sitting here doing nothing for 50 mins now...

Comment: Then check what takes so long: top, iotop, strace...